# How to make the ListView.builder for the coming data from firebase

Tags: flutter

There are two different codes, one is my code and the other is the YouTuber code of which I am watching the video.
First my code :

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todo_app/screens/new_task.dart';
class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
```

_    myHomeState createState() => _myHomeState();
}

```
class _myHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  String uid='';
  @override
  void initState() {
    getUid();
    super.initState();
  }
  getUid()async{
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final User? user = await auth.currentUser;
    setState(() {
      uid = user!.uid;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('TODO'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      ),
      body: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height ,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    color: Colors.white10,
    child: StreamBuilder(stream: 
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tasks').doc(uid).collection('myTasks').snapshots(),
      builder: (context,snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
       return Center(
         child:
         CircularProgressIndicator(),
       );

      }
      else{
       final docs = snapshot.data;

        return ListView.builder(itemCount: , itemBuilder: ( context,  index) {
          return Container(
            child:
            Column(
              children: [
               Text(docs [index] ['title'])
              ],
            ),
          );
        },);
      }
      },),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.white,),
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    onPressed: (){
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>AddTask()));
    },
  ),
);
```

}
}
2nd the Youtuber code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:todo_app/screens/new_task.dart';
class MyHome extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHome({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
```

_    myHomeState createState() => _myHomeState();
}

```
class _myHomeState extends State<MyHome> {
  String uid='';
  @override
  void initState() {
    getUid();
    super.initState();
  }
  getUid()async{
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final User? user = await auth.currentUser;
    setState(() {
      uid = user!.uid;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('TODO'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      ),
      body: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height ,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    color: Colors.white10,
    child: StreamBuilder(stream: 
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tasks').doc(uid).collection('myTasks').snapshots(),
      builder: (context,snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
       return Center(
         child:
         CircularProgressIndicator(),
       );

      }
      else{
       final docs = snapshot.data;

        return ListView.builder(itemCount: , itemBuilder: ( context,  index) {
          return Container(
            child:
            Column(
              children: [
               Text(docs [index] ['title'])
              ],
            ),
          );
        },);
      }
      },),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
    child: Icon(Icons.add,color: Colors.white,),
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    onPressed: (){
      Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>AddTask()));
    },
  ),
);
   }
   }
```

I have the issue in `else{final docs = snapshot.data.documents;}`this is Youtuber code, in my code
there is not showing `.documents;` after `snapshot.data`.
2nd issue:
I have the 2nd issue in `item count: docs. length`  this is the YouTuber code, in my code,
there is no showing `.length` after `docs.`.
3rd issue I am facing :
I have the issue in `Text(docs [index] ['title'])` this is the Youtuber code,
in my code: `Text(docs! [index] ['title'])` flutter was throwing an error 'please add the null check after docs', and I gave the null check, but after giving the null check flutter is throwing another error about `[index]`, the error is :error: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
The video  I am watching is from ten months ago.
I don't know the updated code.
Please help me.
I hope those who would be seeing my code, would be understanding my issue.
link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3kuvRjDS3yk&list=PL9n0l8rSshSnSO4dNTJmKGNa0VNHrCQFR&index=6

Comment: There's a bunch of issues with the formatting of the code which may make it difficult to spot issues. For example `docs [index] ['title']` should be `docs[index]['title']` also `itemCount` is not set which might be the issues here. I'd recommend using IDEs such as VS Code which should highlight and help you see these kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

The youtuber you are following on with is using an outdated version of firestore and the video is probably more than a year old.

Would advise you to get comfortable with reading documentation for example firebase, as they explain that now it's `docs` instead of `documents`.

Change you code to this:

```
 final docs = snapshot.data.docs;

    return ListView.builder(itemCount: docs.length, itemBuilder: ( context,  index)
```

Comment: I also wrote this code but I said in the (final docs = snapshot.data) not showing .docs after .data and in itemCount, there is not showing .length after docs.

Comment: Which documentation should I read?

Comment: It's not showing, because you didn't tell Flutter the type of snapshot you are working with. But using `docs` will work. Also `final List<DocumentSnapshot> docs = snapshot.data.docs` will work.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but Sir, it is not working, still not showing .docs in the last.

Comment: I think I am missing a pkg, What do you suggest?

Comment: Sir, I am a beginner and I want to solve this, so please help me.

Comment: use this in your stream builder `StreamBuilder<AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>(stream:...`

Comment: nothing happened, another error appeared.

Comment: Errors: error: The argument type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>>?'.

Comment: Change it to `Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>`

Comment: Ok, Sir.............

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245521/discussion-between-huzaifa-adil-and-huthaifa-muayyad).